# How to synchronize scrollbars on JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

There are two TextAreas in my application and I want to make the scrollbars slide synchronized when I move one of the scrollbars. But I can't find a way to do that in JavaFX 2.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
TextArea ta1 = new TextArea(), ta2 = new TextArea();
ta1.scrollTopProperty().bindBidirectional(ta2.scrollTopProperty());
```

In common case, you can apply a lookupAll(String) operation at TextArea to find scroll bar inside the TextArea, and bind their values bidirectionally.

Comment: Thanks, your code really does the job! Why is this property called scrollTop?  There is also scrollLeft... These names are confusing...

Comment: Yeah. But there is no hope on their renaming.